# ReqForHelp: Understanding Vf relationship to supplied V and A

Tags: led

Context:
I am a beginner tinkerer at electronics. Conceptually a lot of this is hard for me. But, I plod on. I very much like to use free salvaged components for all sorts of projects, and continue that by salvaging parts for electronics learning/projects.

I have what *was* a solar-charging sensor-activated LED light. It is not intact, the housing is destroyed, but it works. It has in it an LED panel. I want to re-use this panel in other stuff, but have hit a conceptual wall about how to use the vF I measured.

The Solar Light uses a 3.7 V rechargeable LiPo as its storage. It has three settings via a click button. The first of these settings will send 53.9 mA at 2.57 v to the LED panel (measured on the wires between the board and the LED panel). The second sends 54.5 mA at 2.57 V. The third sends 11.75 mA at 2.28 V.
The first two are "bright" and the last is "dim". I can't see any brightness difference between the two 2.57 V settings even though the A is different.

The LED panel has 28 white LEDs wired in parallel. They are the sort that is flat, square, and has no wire leads. Soldered right to a circuitboard with only the tiniest bit of metal showing on two opposing sides to get probes onto. Luckily I can see the traces through the paint to know it is parallel connected.

In the highest current setting (54.5 mA at 2.57 v from the board to the entire LED panel) 
I measured the Vf across multiple individual LEDs, getting a measurement average of .985 V (not mV) with a variance of .015 +/- either side that value. It was starting to get pretty damn hot by the end, since I had to tape over the LEDs to be able to see anything at all as I worked.

But now I am confused, unsure, whatever about whether a Vf measurement at 54.5 mA and 2.57 V is useful if I want to have a 5v supply. I tried using a couple of online calculators for parallel LEDs but they will not accept Vf numbers below 1.

Request:
Could someone help me understand if the Vf I measured is a 'static' thing? I mean, is Vf just Vf no matter what or is Vf dependent on what voltage is supplied to the LED or what current is being supplied? Did I measure a Vf number that is useless to me if I want to use a 3.3 V supply or a 5  V supply? Apologies ahead of time for my thickheadedness, but I just can't make sense of all this.

[image: Parts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone help me understand if the Vf I measured is a 'static' thing? I mean, is Vf just Vf no matter what or is Vf dependent on what voltage is supplied to the LED or what current is being supplied?

[image]

*Figure 1. Small LED current versus voltage curves. Source: [I-V curves](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

LEDs are non-linear devices. They don't have a linear relationship between current and voltage (I-V) as in the case of resistors. Rather, the current increases exponentially with voltage. If an I-V curve is available you can predict what current will flow at a given voltage.

[image]

*Figure 2. Variation in \$ V_f \$ (forward voltage) for the Cree LTST-C170TBKT white LED. Source: [Variations in \$ V_f \$ and binning](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/variations-vf-binning/).*

Because there can be a wide variation in \$ V_f \$ it is generally not a good idea to directly parallel LEDs as the currents through them will then vary significantly. For low voltage applications a series resistor with each LED will help to balance the currents. For higher voltage applications series connection of the LEDs ensures the same current through each.

> The second sends 54.5 mA at 2.57 V. The third sends 11.75 mA at 2.28 V. The first two are "bright" and the last is "dim". I can't see any brightness difference between the two 2.57 V settings even though the A is different.

The currents through the first and second are too close to perceive a difference.

> In the highest current setting (54.5 mA at 2.57 v from the board to the entire LED panel) I measured the Vf across one LED, getting a measurement of .986 V.

There's something wrong there. You are unlikely to be able to see any light at that low voltage. Try measuring again.

> Did I measure a Vf number that is useless to me if I want to use a 3.3 V supply or a 5 V supply? Apologies ahead of time for my thickheadedness, but I just can't make sense of all this.

3.3 V is low for white LEDs. (See the binning article for more on that.)

The linked articles are mine and may help your understanding.

Comment: OK, I'm nearly blind now from measuring and re-measuring and re-measuring across single LEDs on the panel while it's lit up.  Don't know how you people measure stuff like this, as it is SO tiny and SO bright. Rigged my multimeter to itty-bitty jumper wires just to make sure I was cramming enough metal to metal. They read near the same as before: about .985 volts. not millivolts. Same thing +/- tiny fractions on several of them. Using the sideways triangle pointed at a plus sign setting on the multimeter which is what everything online says to use. What do you make of this reading?

Comment: For clarity's sake: Set to the diode marker on the dial (triangle pointing at plus sign) and screen shows diode symbol NOT ohm symbol. Readings are "-.985" when connected one way, and "0L" when connected the opposite way (polarity). Nobody online mentions the negative symbol I get. Also just quintuple-checked the A and V readings I posted in my question - they're the same every time within a few thousandths.

Comment: Trying to grasp why it is that what you say (which I'm sure is the truth) doesn't match what I am measuring (which I'm fairly sure is also true). I feel like I'm going crazy or I'm way dumber than I thought I was. How can I measure over and over and get values that are not allowed by what others say? <banging head on desk>

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using the diode test range with the circuit powered up? That will really mess up your readings and possibly damage your meter if you touch the wrong point. You measure \$ V_f \$ on DC V range with the circuit powered. You can also measure it with the diode test function when the circuit is switched off but it gives a very low test current and may not have enough voltage to turn on the LED. See my [non-return valve analogy](http://lednique.com/what-is-an-led/).

Comment: You might find my video [Plotting an I-V curve](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/) instructional, if a little long winded.

Comment: With LED board disconnected from everything else, using the diode test mode: "0L" no matter which LED I pick and no matter which way around I put the leads onto the LEDs. When powered, the same settings get "-.985". On DCV setting with the lights on, I get 2.645V. So I now 'get' that the Vf must be the 2.645V I read, but doing the diode test properly gets results that don't make sense. Anyway, I'm ending my sidebar on testing - you answered the initial question well!