# Current too low at forward voltage of power led

Tags: led-driver

I bought some RGB power leds, o.a. a Cree XML. 
The spec/description at the (Chinese) site mentioned forward voltage of 3.3-3.9V.
But when driving the led at that voltage I measure much less current than expected. ~0.150mA @ 3.9V instead of ~1A for the Cree led, and something similar for other leds with a max of 700mA.
I need to go above 5V to get the full max current.

Do I misunderstand the meaning of forward voltage? Or is it happening more often that leds are supplied with higher voltage drops (than described).

I planned to use a 5V power supply and a current regulator (mosfet, resistor and transistor feedback) which requires and extra voltage of ~1.2V.
This does not fit if forward voltage is that high.

Comment: My answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353955/reqforhelp-understanding-vf-relationship-to-supplied-v-and-a/353975#353975 discusses binning of LEDs to achieve consistency between samples. It won't explain the very high Vf but may help in some way. You should really test the LEDs using a current source rather than a voltage source.

Comment: Watch out for high-powered LED's. The 10 mm dome type on a ceramic plate often has 2 LED's in series, and another pair parallel to the first. Turn-on voltage is about 6 to 7 volts. They can do the same with RGB LED's except they have six connections instead of two. At full power they MUST be mounted to a large heat-sink with thermal epoxy.

Comment: How did you run these at the right voltage? With a variable power supply? Or did you use a current limiting resistor and measure the voltage across the LED?

Comment: If it's a chinese site then there's a decent chance the specs are simply wrong. There's also a good chance the part is not the part you think it is.

Comment: I measured with voltage supply, but using limiting resistor, measuring voltage across the led and across the resistor (to get the current).  I think I suffer from wrong specs at aliexpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cree [spec](http://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/XLampXML-11E.pdf) shows 2.9 - 3.5 V for 700 mA

[image]

You should be able to engineer a current controller that works at 5 V without any problems.
Perhaps something simple like this, though it will have a thermal variation of current which can be reduce by putting the NPN close the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX0nTn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Any suggestion for a current controller - must be very cheap (<$0.20)  because I need to make many?

Comment: Added to the answer ....but <$0.20 seems a bit aggressive.

Comment: Yes it is ;-) Found a more-or-less similar schema on a blog. But that did not use a resistor R3. R3 will increase the voltage drop over R1, isn't it?

Comment: R3 has no real effect but is simply a safety limit on base current. The base current is only uA.